# I have given key prop to the child but still showing: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using moongodb and express in backend.
This is my component.

```
 return (
     <>
         <Addnote />
         <div className="row my-3">
             {notes.map((note) => {
                 return <Noteitem note={note} key={note._id}/>;
             })}
         </div>
     </>
)
```

Comment: What is the contents of `notes` here? Seems that there are entries where `note._id` is missing or not unique.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `note._id` is not unique. You can fix it to be unique or use the item's index like so:

```js
{notes.map((note, i) => {
  return <Noteitem note={note} key={i} />;
})}
```

or shortened to:

```js
{notes.map((note, i) => (
  <Noteitem note={note} key={i} />;
))}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think

```
{notes.map((note) => {
```

should be replaced by

```
 {notes.map((note) => (
```

the bracket replace { with (